# Перестал работать discord бот на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Я решил со своих старых наработок (которые раньше работали) написать нового бота.
Вот мой код:

```
token = 'токен'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот залогинился')
    #resource.con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    #resource.cur = resource.con.cursor()
    #print(client.guilds)



client.run(token)
```

После запуска, выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Nikita/Desktop/Bot/Role Upper/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run   
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 585, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 463, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 471, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 425, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 750, in parse_guild_create
    guild = self._get_create_guild(data)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 725, in _get_create_guild
    guild._from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 296, in _from_data
    self._sync(guild)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 325, in _sync
    self._add_channel(VoiceChannel(guild=self, data=c, state=self._state))
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 553, in __init__
    self._update(guild, data)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 584, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
```

Это новый бот, которого я создал и при первом запуске он нормально работал, но после добавления на сервер и перезапуска, он перестал работать и начал выдавать вот эту ошибку.
Я уже пробовал `pip install -U discord.py` и `python3 -m install -U discord.py`.
Также уже переустанавливал библиотеку, но ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблеми с авторизацией. Проверьте токен и все что связано с авторизацией.